# Editable React-MaterialUI TextField component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I'm creating an **editable text field** using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/) and React.

- When you are outside the text field it appears like a `div` or a `span` element:
  [image]
- But when you `mouseover` it, an edit icon appear:

[image]

- And when you ckick it, the message becomes like a classic text field:
  [image]
- The issue I have is that everything works fine except the fact that I can't click on the edit icon (it becomes *flashing*)
- I'm sharing what I already did: https://codesandbox.io/s/jny3704v63
- I know the source of the problem but I don't know how to fix it! The problem is that when you `mouseover` the edit icon, we are in a `mouseout` event of the text field and the `handleMouseOut` function will be executed.
- You can check that by commenting the content of `handleMouseOut` but the icon will not disappear when you leave the text field!

Any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix this by using `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` instead of `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`. You can read about the differences here: https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave

[image: Edit React-MaterialUI-EditableTextField]